How to sort the output of lists in AppleScript into an array of properties of each item?
I have the following AppleScript:
tell application "System Events"
    set _P to a reference to (application process "Finder")
    set _W to a reference to windows of _P
    [_W's name, _W's size, _W's position]
end tell

This will return a list of Finder window names, followed by a list of window sizes {x,y}, followed by a list of window positions {x,y}, like so:
{{"name of window 1", "name of window 2", "name of window 3"}, {{547, 420}, {537, 140}, {1324, 502}}, {{3674, 900}, {523, 194}, {3646, 865}}}

How can I parse this data so that it is formatted as a list of the name, size, and position of each window, like this?
{{"name of window 1", {window 1 size}, {window 1 position}},
{"name of window 2", {window 2 size}, {window 2 position}},
{"name of window 3", {window 3 size}, {window 3 position}}}

The ultimate goal here is to be able to save and later restore named/numbered lists of window positions for an app (other than Finder, since I've already found another method that works for Finder, which unfortunately doesn't seem to work with any other app).
